# OpenNLP, Training Named Entity Recognition on unsupported languages: clarifications needed

Tags: opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I want to experiment NER on a specific domain, that is location names extraction from travel offers in Italian language.

So far I've got that I need to prepare the training set by myself, so I'm going to put the

```
<START:something><END>
```

tags in some offers from my training set.

But looking at OpenNLP documentation on how to train for NER, I ended up in having a couple of questions:

1) When defining the START/END tags, I'm I free to use whatever name inside the tags (where I wrote "something" a few line above) or is there a restricted set to be bound?

2) I noticed that the call to the training tool

```
opennlp TokenNameFinderTrainer
```

takes a string representing the language as the first argument. What is that for? Considering I want to train a model on Italian language that is NOT supported, is there any additional task to be done before I could train for NER?

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, you can specify multiple types. If the training file contains multiple types, the created model will also be able to detect these multiple types.

2) I think that "lang" parameter has the same meaning/use of other commands (e.g. `opennlp TokenizerTrainer -lang it ...`)